# How to ensure a certain script tag remains at the top of <head>

Tags: javascript, pageload

I am working on a large website with a lot of existing third-party products already set up on it.
I want to add a cookie consent script, which needs to be the first script executed.
So I have added it at the top of `<head>` and when I do View Source I can see it is there at the top.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://path/to/cookie/consent/stuff/cookie_script.js"> 
  ...
```

And then further down various other external libraries and frameworks are loaded: jQuery, GoogleAds, Hotjar and so on

```
    ...
          <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
       ...
</head>
```

But by the time the page has finished loading, when I inspect the DOM using the Web Dev Tools, I can see that my cookie script is no longer the first element in the `<head>`. Some other elements have been inserted in front of it.

```
    <head>
    <script src="https://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd.js?cb=%2Fr20100101"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/js/rum.js"></script>
    ...
    // Cookie consent script has been pushed down to here
      <script src="https://path/to/cookie/consent/stuff/cookie_script.js">
    ...
    </head>
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: If your script is the first one in the source code, regardless of scripts added dynamically, it will have been processed before the other ones.  The order doesn't matter at that point, because the browsers will parse the page, process your script file fully before moving on to process further scripts which would insert the dynamic other scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These elements are inserted AFTER the page is loaded from your server, this means that by the time that these scripts are loaded and executed, your script have already run.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect this programmatically using something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var topScript = document.querySelector("script");
  if (topScript.getAttribute(src) != ...) {
     //takeAction
  } 
}, yourTimeout);
```

For your action, you can use `alert` to warn the user to close/not save the page. Alternatively, you could try moving the script you want to be at the top back to the top